# I'm having cannot find module error in node js and tried everything

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to work on a script that generate art using node js

im getting :

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/mayday/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
```

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

this is my code :  [image]

this is my terminal :  [image]

Comment: Have you re installed node_module

Comment: No, how do to that ? npm install ?

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i`. This removes the current `node_modules` and reinstalls them, since what you have now is obviously incomplete.

Comment: are you sure you running the `node` executable in the correct folder?

Comment: Hi @MustafaAli. For your future questions, try to not upload images of code/errors. And here's why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question